# C# Console.Write print out in text file?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

Can I make code like this to print out in a text file using Console.Write ?

```
 Console.Write(" Enter your ID: ");
 int ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.Write(" Enter your Name: ");
 string Name = Console.ReadLine();
 Console.WriteLine(" Thank you! your logged in as" +Name+ +ID);
```

Please Help!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [How to: Write to a Text File (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you need to write in a file in your particular case but if you want `Console.WriteLine` to write in a file you may use `Console.SetOut(sw);`

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
Console.SetOut(sw);
Console.WriteLine("Hello file");
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked well but how can prevent overwriting on this file?  Every time I enter records it overwrites the previous one in the text file.

Comment: Note the parameter in creating FileStream, "FileMode.Create". Look into your other options like FileMode.Append.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Unfortunately, it shows up an error on line 7, I can't identify it. Here is my code screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/code1f.jpg/

Comment: Sorry, my bad, actually you should use `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Test.txt", true);` without the `FileStream`. (I deleted the previous comment since I couldn't edit it)